# How to install this ceiling lamp

Tags: lamp

I bought [this ceiling lamp on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B006P9PO2O/ref=pe_385721_37038051_pe_217191_31005151_M3T1_dp_1) and I am trying to fit it. Usually the wires coming from the ceiling are connected to the base of the bulb through some sort of connecting block, where each wire is pinched by a small screw so it can't get away.

But incredibly in this lamp there is nothing like that, just holes and nothing to block the wires!

Does anybody have any clue about how to properly attach electric wires to this thing?

Pictures available below. Full-screen picture of the relevant part here: [picture](http://uppix.net/wrJy5Q.jpg)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Procedure**

- Turn off power to the lighting circuit
- Test that power is off using a non-contact voltage detector (NCV) and/or Cat-II multimeter.
- If necessary to prevent cable chafing, fit a [cable grommet](http://www.toolstation.com/shop/Electrical/Cable+Management/Rubber+Grommet+25mm+Open/d190/sd2460/p77988) to the backplate cable opening. (since the backplate may be heated by the lamp, you may need to look for a grommet that can be used in hot conditions)
- Strip the insulation from the ends of the live and neutral wires.
- To the screw attach an earth wire (bare or green/yellow in UK)
- In the hole above the embossed "L" push the live wire (brown in UK).
- In the hole above the embossed "N" push the neutral wire (blue in UK).

**Notes**

- The push-fit connections are unusual in UK fittings and are intended for solid-core wires (not stranded)
- The holes connected to the metal strip are not for powering the light.
- The fitting appears to be designed for use with a separate junction box fitted in the ceiling.
- Live wires from a light-switch sometimes have the wrong colour insulation but are marked with red tape (indicating switched-live).
- Typical wiring for a ceiling lighting fitting in the UK is as shown below

[image]

Note that this image does not show the strain relief that must be present on the hanging cable. Fittings with exposed metal parts will need a protective earth connection. The one you have looks like it particularly needs this!

Comment: It may be well to recommend that there should also be an safety ground wire attached to the screw on the metal part of the picture next to the ground symbol. Also this style of push in wire terminal is most likely intended for a solid conductor of a certain guage.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, I'll incorporate your advice in to the answer.

Comment: I'd also be wary of that metal hole for the wire. It's hard to tell from the picture, but if the edges of it are not made to be smooth, you should not run wires directly through that. It's very unusual for a fixture to require a box connector (which clamps the wires down) but definitely you do not want the possibility of the wire rubbing against a sharp edge.

Comment: @gregmac: Thanks, incorporated. I suspect it may not be needed in this specific fitting but it's a good general point.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The answer was this: I inserted the 2 wires in the 2 top holes and after a few millimeters inside they got pinched and firmly blocked by some mechanism inside. Now I can't remove them, it's like a connecting block hidden inside without screws.

Comment: @drake035: When needed, you may be able to remove the wires by twisting and pulling.

Comment: I hope so, although I've been told it's usually not possible except if there's a mechanism for it. In this case, on the third picture on can see square holes on the sides, he said that perhaps by inserting something in there it can release the wires. Not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Drake the square holes next to the round ones are the releases. In the U.S. 14 awg wire is the max wire size for these type fixtures, if you have several I would pigtail so if the backstab fails only that light will go out not all of them past this point.